# How to create a ModelResource for a Model that inherits another Model using django-tastypie?

Tags: python, django, tastypie

My django models looks like:

```
class Session(models.Model):
    ...

class Document(models.Model):
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Invoice(Document):
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    # and some other fields

class SupplyRequest(Document):
    # fields here
```

That way, every `Invoice` and `SupplyRequest` instances are linked to a `Session` and have a `date_created` attribute. OK. So, I created a `ModelResource` for `Session` and for `Invoice`, imagining that Tastypie can walk through `Document` model fields transparently. But does not work:

```
class SessionResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Session.objects.all()
        ...

class InvoiceResource(ModelResource):

    session = fields.ForeignKey(SessionResource, 'session')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Invoice.objects.all()
        ...
```

When I try to serialize an Invoice I got the following error message:

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'api_dispatch_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 1, 'resource_name': 'session'}' not found.
```

Is there any way to deal with model inheritance using Tastypie?

I've forgotten to mention that `Document` model is an abstract class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must have forgotten to set the url SessionResource.

```
from tastypie.api import Api

api = Api()

api.register(SessionResource())

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^api/', include(api.urls)),
)
```

You do this in urls.py?

Hugs.

Comment: God! Betrayed by fatigue... you're entirely right! Thank you.